# how can I override source dirs in gradle BUT only for this one annoying subproject

Tags: gradle

We have one main project and two subprojects.  One of the subprojects is the playframework which has a "unique" build structure.  How can I override the source directories BUT only for that one subproject such that all other projects are using the standard layout of source directories src/main/java, etc.

I tried the first answer which is not working and for my directory structure

```
 stserver
     build.gradle (1)
     project1
     webserver
         build.gradle (2)
```

The 2nd gradle file is this

```
sourceSets.main{
  java.srcDirs = ['app']
}

task build << {
  println "source sets=$sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs"
}
```

When I run this, it prints out stserver/app as my srcDir instead of stserver/webserver/app????  What am I doing wrong here?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: I recommend to study [Working with source sets](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:source_sets) and [Multi-project Builds](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#multi_project_builds) in the Gradle user guide. Also have a look at the many samples that come with the full Gradle distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the docs Peter has suggested. I have a ready `build.gradle` that I have working with Play Framework 2.0~, so I'll share it here in hope you'll find some useful setup tips.

My project structure:

```
+- master/
  +- build.gradle  <-- contains common setup, 
                       and applies 'java' plugin to all subprojects
+- ui/             <-- project using Play framework
  +- build.gradle  <-- excerpt from this file is posted below
```

The excerpt from `build.gradle`

```groovy
repositories{
  maven{
    //Play dependencies will be downloaded from here
    url " http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"
  }
}

//Optional but useful. Finds 'play' executable from user's PATH
def findPlay20(){
  def pathEnvName = ['PATH', 'Path'].find{ System.getenv()[it] != null }
  for(path in System.getenv()[pathEnvName].split(File.pathSeparator)){
    for(playExec in ['play.bat', 'play', 'play.sh']){
      if(new File(path, playExec).exists()){
        project.ext.playHome = path
        project.ext.playExec = new File(path, playExec)
        return
      }
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("""'play' command was not found in PATH.
Make sure you have Play Framework 2.0 installed and in your path""")
}

findPlay20()

configurations{
  //Configuration to hold all Play dependencies
  providedPlay
}

dependencies{
  providedPlay "play:play_2.9.1:2.0+"
  //Eclipse cannot compile Play template, so you have to tell it to
  //look for play-compiled classes
  providedPlay files('target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed')

  //other dependencies
}

sourceSets.main{
  java.srcDirs = ['app', 'target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main']
  //Make sure Play libraries are visible during compilation
  compileClasspath += configurations.providedPlay
}

//This task will copy your project dependencies (if any) to 'lib'
//folder, which Play automatically includes in its compilation classpath
task copyPlayLibs(type: Copy){
  doFirst { delete 'lib' }
  from configurations.compile
  into 'lib'
}

//Sets up common play tasks to be accessible from gradle.
//Can be useful if you use gradle in a continuous integration 
//environment like Jenkins.
//
//'play compile' becomes 'gradle playCompile'
//'play run' becomes 'gradle playRun', and so on.
[ ['run',     [copyPlayLibs]],
  ['compile', [copyPlayLibs]],
  ['clean',   []],
  ['test',    []],
  ['doc',     [copyPlayLibs]],
  ['stage',   [copyPlayLibs]] ].each { cmdSpec ->
    def playCommand = cmdSpec[0]
    def depTasks = cmdSpec[1]
    task "play${playCommand.capitalize()}" (type: Exec,
                                            dependsOn: depTasks,
                                            description: "Execute 'play ${playCommand}'") {
     commandLine playExec, playCommand
    }
}

//Interate playClean and playCompile task into standard
//gradle build cycle
clean.dependsOn "playClean"
[compileScala, compileJava]*.dependsOn "playCompile"

//Include Play libraries in Eclipse classpath
eclipse {
  classpath {
    plusConfigurations += configurations.providedPlay
  }
}
```

*Note:* I have just extracted the above from an existing bigger gradle file, so it might be missing some things, so no guarantees:) Hope it's useful anyway. Good luck.